# Property with type SEL in Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, properties, selector

I'd like to declare a property with type `SEL` like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) SEL mySelector;
```

Is "`assign`" correct here? Perhaps `assign` can be omitted?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

assign is the correct annotation here. You use assign for any primitive types. The alternatives (weak, strong/retain) rely on the property pointing at an object to function. I believe the compiler won't even let you declare the wrong type of property for this. If you really wanted to you could omit the assign as it is the default.

Comment: Confirmed and +1, this `@property (nonatomic, weak) SEL tapSelector;` causes an error, "property with 'weak' attribute must be of object type."